# Could someone explain Spring Security BasePermission.Create?

Tags: java, security, spring, spring-security

I am working on a project that involves Spring Security ACL and I came across the create permission `BasePermission.CREATE`. Would someone please explain how this is supposed to work or what it allows someone to do?

It is my understanding that each object has an acl, and each acl has many ace's, and each ace has an sid and a permission. How can you grant permission on an object to create it, if it must be created in order to attach the acl to it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring security grants permissions on domain objects indirectly via the [ObjectIdentity](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/index.html) interface.

As you mention, by far the usual case is that you create or obtain the domain object first, and then construct a `ObjectIdentityImpl` for the domain object:

```
MyDomainObject secured = new MyDomainObject();
ObjectIdentity securedIdentity = new ObjectIdentityImpl(secured);
```

You then use the `ObjectIdentity` instance to retrieve the ACL using the spring security framework.

However, this is not the only way to use object identity. You can pass a reference to objectIdentity that is not the actual business object, but has some means of identifying it, if it were created.

For example, imagine we wanted to secure files. We could create ObjectItentity with a `java.io.File` instance that is being secured. The `File` object that is in the identity is only a reference to the file - it no the actual file - the file may not even exist, yet we have an ObjectIdentity that we can then reason about security and fetch ACLs for.

This pattern can be applied to any kind of domain object. Create an `DomainObjectPrototype` implementation that describes the domain object in terms of the domain features needed to secure it, but doesn't actually need a reference to the domain object. YOu can think of this as the details needed for some service to actually create that domain object.

PS: let me confess that I've never used spring security, but the design pattern seems pretty clear to me after looking at an [example](http://www.techinfopad.com/spring/100504623-acl-denies-access-to-basepermissionread-although-containing-a-the-appropriate.html).

EDIT: I've updated this to hopefully make it clearer - it's not necessary to create implementations of ObjectIdentity as I originaly wrote.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would like to clarify though. Do you mean if I want to restrict creation of a Widget class, I might do something like the following? 

    ObjectIdentity securedIdentity = new ObjectIdentityImpl(Widget.class,Widget.RESERVED_CLASS_ID);

I would then check if the create permission was allowed to some sid.

Comment: When access control is not dependent upon the specific instances of Widget class, then you can do that. If you need instance-specific control, then create a WidgetPrototype class that includes the domain attributes needed to define access control.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking more broadly there are two types of permissions: class and instance.  Object creation is a class permission - you have permission to create a new instance.  It's meaningless when you try to apply it to an individual instance.  Read permission can be either.  You can have permission to read all of the instances, or maybe you only have permission to read a handful of explicitly enumerated instances.

If you're ever confused think of the classic "surprise birthday party email" problem.  This is an office email sent to everyone EXCEPT the birthday boy to plan the surprise birthday party.  In this case you need a class CREATE permission to create and send the email message, and everyone has class READ permission to read the message.  However one person has an instance DENY READ permission so that he, alone, can't read the message.

Comment: I understand the need for a CREATE permission. My question was how to use it in spring security specifically. Thank you though.