# Can Spring Security ACLs be applied on the domain class level?

Tags: spring-security, acl

Is it possible to apply ACL permissions on domain Classes (instead of domain instances?).  I have a scenario where I would like to offer one class of users blanket permissions to completely CRUD on domain objects, while a second class of user must have specific ACL entries to do this.

It's certainly possible to mix ACL entries with role based permissions to achieve this, but I feel like there's a more elegant solution possible of Spring ACLs can work on the class level in addition to the instance level.

I'm looking over the meager [Spring Security ACL documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733947/could-someone-explain-spring-security-basepermission-create).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the interface `ObjectIdentity`. It represents object that is protected in the system.

```
/**
 * Obtains the actual identifier. This identifier must not be reused to represent other domain objects with
 * the same javaType.
 *
 * Because ACLs are largely immutable, it is strongly recommended to use
 * a synthetic identifier (such as a database sequence number for the primary key). Do not use an identifier with
 * business meaning, as that business meaning may change in the future such change will cascade to the ACL
 * subsystem data.
 *
 * @return the identifier (unique within this type; never null)
 */
Serializable getIdentifier();

/**
 * Obtains the "type" metadata for the domain object. This will often be a Java type name (an interface or a class)
 * &ndash; traditionally it is the name of the domain object implementation class.
 *
 * @return the "type" of the domain object (never null).
 */
String getType();
```

As you can see Spring Security uses `Serializable` to describe type of the identifier. 
So it is possible to use String with class name.

You would need to update SQL schema as authors of Spring Security assumed that most people would identify objects by long/integer ids.

```
create table acl_object_identity(
...
object_id_class bigint not null,
object_id_identity bigint not null,
```

As I checked, `JdbcMutableAclService` is able to handle that customization as it uses only `ObjectIdentity` interface.

Study the source code of the `org.springframework.security.acls` packages.